# How to: get Date, Time and Time zone from single DateTimePicker Control

Tags: .net, windows, datetime, timezone

I am developing an application in which I am trying to fetch Date, Time and Time Zone from single `DateTimePicker` control. Can anybody help to resolve this?

**Edit 1**
I am using .NET Framework 2.0. Now I am able to fetch Date and Time with Single `DateTimePicker` by setting its `CustomFormat` property as

```
dtpicker2.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy,hh:mm:ss"
```

Now my problem is to fetch TimeZone.

**Edit 2**
Now here is one more issue, if I set `DateTimePicker`'s format property to Time, it shows me something like `2:30:00 PM`. I am storing this in a file and reassigning it to the `DateTimePicker` control.
Can anybody help me out, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it using a DateTimePicker on it's own.

Rather, you are going to have to have sort of composite control which has a DateTimePicker on it, as well as another control which will serve as the offset.

This control could be a numeric up/down control which you would use for the hour, minute, second, etc, etc offset (or just a textbox for that matter).

Another option is if you have a location (in the form of latitude and longitude, [which you can obtain via Google through HTTP](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding_Direct) if you have an address), to use the [Timezone API function at GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) which will allow you to pass a latitude and longitude value and it will return the timezone for that location.  That, along with the [TZ database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) and the [ZoneInfo project](http://www.codeplex.com/zoneinfo) will allow you to determine the offset at that particular date/time (which isn't the same for all locations and all dates).

Comment: I was about to +1... until the mention of geocoding. Don't do it, chaps, especially for defaults for UIs: it's really very very unreliable and will just annoy your users.

Comment: @Jeremy McGee: Note how I said if you have an address.  I believe you think I'm implying one should geocode by IP address, which I agree, is *very* unreliable.  Geocoding doesn't imply using an IP address to resolve physical location.  If one has an address, Google does an excellent job of translating that to a lat/long pair consistently and accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Actually, I am developing a windows application, in which I was trying to get input as Date, Time and Time Zone. I found out the way to get Date and Time, with 2 different DateTimePicker controls, of course it can be achieved with single control, but I used 2 for the sake of simplicity. I have found one class which is equivalent to TimeZoneInfo in .net 3.5. Now I am making use of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) you can change the *Format Property* to **Custom**, and specify the *CustomFormat Property* as  **dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss**. This will allow you to in your code use

```
DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
dt.Date
dt.TimeOfDay
```

Unfortunately the *DateTimePicker* does not have the built in [TimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx) but you can make use of

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

Also have a look at this Question

[Custom Formating a DateTimePicker using CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836354/custom-formating-a-datetimepicker-using-cultureinfo)

Answer (score 0):

The [Any+Time(TM) Datepicker/Timepicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) now supports time zone input/output, selection and conversion.  It should be compatible with .NET (see the Troubleshooting section on the web page if you have problems) and has pretty extensive timezone support (see the section on the web page about UTC offsets).  Hopefully it will meet your needs.