# C#: DateTimePicker control's default timezone

Tags: c#, .net

What is the default timezone/kind for the DateTime value of the DateTimePicker of the .NET. Is it UTC or the local time zone of the machine at the run time, or is the the timezone of the machine where my code was compiled? Or will it be ambiguous if not specified explicitly within the code?

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows Forms control? Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978581/how-to-get-date-time-and-time-zone-from-single-datetimepicker-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default TimeZone will be the local TimeZone of the machine **executing** the code in question.